# Powershell - Select-object keeping same columns throughout script

Tags: powershell, scripting

OK. I'm just drawing a blank here or I'm missing something obvious.  In a Powershell (V3) script, I'm calling

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'SAMAccoutnName -like $ADUserName' -Properties Name,SamAccountName,EmailAddress | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, EmailAddress
```

It lists the data in the column format I would expect

```
Name           SamAccountName          EmailAddress
------         ---------------         ------------
User Name      username                user.name@co.com
```

That's not the problem. When I call a different command after that in the script (Exchange 2013 actually)

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity username | Select-Object Name, SAMAccountName, PrimarySMTPAddress
```

I only get the corresponding columns from the earlier Select-Object with no headers:

```
User Name     username
```

Even if I specifically ask for a different set such as that "PrimarySMTPAddress" from above.

What am I missing here? This is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the Exchange Cmdlets right here in front of me right now, but uh, what properties does `Get-Mailbox -Identity username | select *` actually return? Does the return object actually contain the properties that you're trying to select?

Comment: That returns quite a bit of properties but I've been able to run that above command and return those properties from a shell by itself, it's just that in the script it seems to only want to continue to use that fist Select-Object table that I used with the Get-ADUser ahead of it in the same script. While in the shell I can run them both manually and I get what I would expect, two different Select-Object sets with two headers for two tables.  There has got to be something in the way PowerShell runs a script that changes that behavior, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Can you show us the entire script/function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the fact that if you run select-object as a last cmdlet in pipeline with different set of properties, PowerShell will not "implicitly" call `Out-Default` for each command, so it won't "reset" formatting.

But what is not done implicitly, can always be done explicitly.
Just output any command (maybe except last one) to `Out-Default`:

```
ls | select Name | Out-Default
ls | select DirectoryName
```